# Building Class path using Maven Fails

Tags: java, linux, maven, build, classpath

I am working with the [Knowledge Graph Identification repository](https://github.com/linqs/KnowledgeGraphidentification) from git.According to the README.md file, I was able to download the dataset using `batsh fetchDataset.sh`.Then I tried to build the classpath using Maven using the following command.

```
~/KnowledgeGraphIdentification/nell_lazy$ mvn dependency:build-classpath -Dmdep.outputFile=classpath.out
```

But the build fails with the following message.

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building kgi 1.0.-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[WARNING] The POM for edu.umd.cs:psl-groovy:jar:1.1 is missing, no dependency information available
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 0.306 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2018-10-15T16:28:45+05:30
[INFO] Final Memory: 9M/303M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project kgi: Could not resolve dependencies for project edu.umd.cs.psl.kgi:kgi:jar:1.0.-SNAPSHOT: Failure to find edu.umd.cs:psl-groovy:jar:1.1 in https://scm.umiacs.umd.edu/maven/lccd/content/repositories/psl-releases/ was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of psl-releases has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/DependencyResolutionException
```

Hence I checked my Maven and Java installations.

```
Apache Maven 3.3.9
Maven home: /usr/share/maven
Java version: 1.8.0_181, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "linux", version: "4.15.0-34-generic", arch: "amd64", family: "unix"
```

Hence, I'd appreciate some input with regard to why my classpath build using maven fails here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just got this running and thought of posting the solution.
Since I was running the early version of psl, I wasn't able to build the classpath as the KGI artifact isn't available in the recent version.

So just a side note for any new users: 
I was able to build it successfully by replacing the `pom.xml` file with this CANARY version `pom.xml` available [here](https://linqs-data.soe.ucsc.edu/maven/repositories/psl-releases/org/linqs/psl/CANARY/psl-CANARY.pom). 
Along with that, the following psl directories

- psl-cli
- psl-core
- psl-groovy
- psl-parser

from [this repo](https://github.com/linqs/psl) need to be made available under the experiment that you're proceeding with.

Then the following will successfully build the classpath creating the `classpath.out` file

```
mvn dependency:build-classpath -Dmdep.outputFile=classpath.out
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert in your domain, but it seems that the mvn repo that you want has moved, check this out and hope it helps :

https://github.com/linqs/psl/wiki/Migrating-to-PSL-2#maven-repository-move

https://github.com/linqs/psl/issues/33

Comment: Thank you for your response. I changed the repo path in the pom.xml file.This downloads the dependencies but fails with the following error. `[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project kgi: Could not resolve dependencies for project edu.umd.cs.psl.kgi:kgi:jar:1.0.-SNAPSHOT: The following artifacts could not be resolved: edu.emory.mathcs:csparsej:jar:1.0, org.ujmp:ujmp-complete:jar:0.2.4, de.mathnbits:mathnbitsSTL:jar:1.0, com.wcohen:secondstring:jar:20120620: Could not find artifact edu.emory.mathcs:csparsej:jar:1.0 in psl-releases (http://maven.linqs.org/maven/repositories/psl-releases/) `